# Cypress tests passes with `cypress open`, but fails with `cypress run`

Tags: cypress

I wrote the e2e tests. They pass all the time if I start them with cypress open.
But if I use this command: **cypress run --browser chrome --headed --no-exit --spec 'tests/e2e/specs/Samples.ts**.
I get many different errors. These errors are not similar. Some of them I don't know how to fix.
And the important fact: **If I open developer tools and restart the tests, all tests will pass. The same for Chrome and firefox.**
I have tried using different versions of cypress but to no avail.
I guess the error types are not important in my issue, but I will explain one of them.
[image]
After the 8th step, cypress reports that the page has loaded and redirects to the login page. This could mean that the
localStorage with the token was accidentally cleared. If I open developer tools and restart the tests, all tests will pass.
The test is very simple. Also, I use two custom functions.

```
describe('Samples', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.deleteAccount();
  });

  context('Create sample', () => {
    const SAMPLE_DATA = {
      name: 'Test',
      description: 'Description',
      compound: 'Compound1; Compound1',
    };

    afterEach(() => {
      cy.get('[data-test-id=btn-create]').click();
      cy.location('hash').should('match', /\/samples\/\d+$/);
      // archive
      cy.get('[data-test-id=btn-more-menu]').click();
      cy.get('[data-test-id=btn-archive]').click();
      cy.get('[data-test-id=btn-restore]');
    });

    it('should create sample without device', () => {
      cy.visit(urlPages.app.SAMPLES);
      cy.get('[data-test-id=btn-show-create-sample-modal]').click();
      cy.get('[data-test-id=input-name]').type(SAMPLE_DATA.name);
      cy.get('[data-test-id=input-description]').type(SAMPLE_DATA.description);
      cy.get('[data-test-id=input-compounds]').type(SAMPLE_DATA.compound);
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: In my expirience run and open commands work a bit differently and - your page has not fully loaded by the time you start typing the data.  I would try putting a arbitrary `cy.wait(4000)` before getting inputts and typing. If this works - you can find a focal point whitch to make sure the page is loaded. For example JQ command `document.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but according to the Cypress best practices (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks, afterEach should be used sparingly and you should perform any necessary cleanup in the beforeEach so you can ensure a clean environment before each test run.

Perhaps eliminating the afterEach and changing your beforeEach to the following will help:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.deleteAccount();
    cy.login();
  });
```

I also think that the 2nd afterEach may be more reliable if it were simply a function that you called explicitly at that end of each test.